# define enum inner class with hexa values

Tags: java, enums

how can i define inner enum class with hexa values?
I tried  to do the following thing:

```
public class A {

    public static enum B {

        VALUE_1((byte) 0x1),
        VALUE_2((byte) 0x2);

        private byte value;

        private byte B(byte value) {
            return this.value = value;
        }

        byte getValue() {
            return value;
        }
    }

    public A() {
        //DOES SOMETHING
    }
}
```

1. I am getting the error A.B constructor is undefined, although I do have a constructor
2. why do I have to have a constructor?

Comment: Hint: this is super basic java syntax. In the end, enums are just "special" classes. Thus a constructor for an enum follows the exact same rules as any other constructor. And obviously you didn't learn about these rules yet. So: learn things in order. There isn't much point in dealing with enums while you dont know how to correctly write down a ctor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I am getting the error A.B constructor is undefined, although I do
>   have a constructor

What you defined is not a constructor but a `private` method :

```
private  byte B (byte value) {
    return this.value = value;
}
```

A constructor has no return type, neither `void` and so it has to return nothing.

> why do I have to have a constructor?

You have a constructor but this is the generated no arg constructor :

```
B () {...}
```

You don't want any constructor. You want a constructor that suits to the enum value declaration :

```
VALUE_1((byte) 0x1),
VALUE_2((byte) 0x2);
```

This is the constructor you want :

```
private B (byte value) {
   this.value = value;
}
```

Comment: Could you also address the 2nd part of the question?

Comment: Sure. I reformulated.

Comment: Thanks, much appreciated!